# ANS (.raw) audio format

Tags: audio

I have a file which is a recorded voice of a single word. The format of this audio file for me is unknown. Could you help me to decode or figure out how it is compressed?
I was trying to open it as a PCM (8/16 bits), VOX, uLaw, aLaw, but it does not work.. all I can hear is a loud noise.
Audio file example is at: 
http://www45.zippyshare.com/v/91135513/file.html
It contains hearable word in english: "approaching", but I don't know how to decode this.
Have you ever seen something like this?